# filtering 2nd and 3rd level host requests

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-4

In a rails application host requests need to be filtered on both a 2nd OR a 3rd level domain request.

At present, I can filter on either with one of the first two statements, but not both with the following regex

```
@site ||= if match = request.host.match(/.*?([^.]+\.[^.]+$)/)
@site ||= if match = request.host.match(/.*?([^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$)/)
  domain = match[1]
  Site.find_by_host(domain)
```

How can a 2nd level or 3rd level request be handled properly?

Comment: Please update your post with sample host strings including expected output.

Comment: assume `3.domain.com` and `domain.com` the Site class having `3.domain.com, first` and `domain.com, second` entries would search for each of these strings and return a specific result for each

Comment: I'm still confused. What is specific result? This is what I asked for.  Do you want to capture domain.com, mail.domain.com etc but not sub.mail.domain.com?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to capture second and third level domains and reject everything else, you can try this regex:

```
/(?i)((?<=\s|^)(?:[a-z0-9\-]+\.){1,2}[a-z0-9]+)(?=(?:[\s\/:])|$)/
```

See live demo at [rubular.com](http://rubular.com/r/bBuRDtSAIf)

Input:

```
google.com facebook.com
docs.google.com
search.google.com/list
www.microsoft.com
foo.bar.google.com
```

Output:

```
google.com facebook.com     | match
docs.google.com             | match
search.google.com/list      | match
www.microsoft.com           | match
foo.bar.google.com          | no match
```